# i am getting permission denied after writing rules in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
    import React, { useReducer, useState ,re} from 'react';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import database from '../firebase/firebase';
import snapshot from '../firebase/firebase';
import '../App.css';
import { auth } from 'firebase';

const AddTasks = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const newLocal = null;
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(newLocal);
    const [task, setTask] = useState('');
    const date = new Date()
```

> here i want to add task with user but gettin permission issue want to set users=> task but it gives me getState is not a function so i tried
> eturn (dispatch, getState) but its do nothing

```
    const addTask = () => {
//  return (dispatch, getState) => {
//       const uid =  getState().auth.uid
         console.log(selectedDate);
        const payload = { id: uuid(), text: task, completed: false, addedAt: JSON.stringify(selectedDate)}
        console.log(payload)
```

> i tried ref(`users/${uid}/tasks`) but not working

```
const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child('tasks');
            return dbtasksWrapper.child(payload.id).update(payload).then(() => { 
                    dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload })
                 })   
            setTask('');
            setSelectedDate(null);   
        //  }
     }
   
return (
    <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
        addTask();
    } }>
        <input className="input-group-prepend" value={task} placeholder="Enter your Task" onChange={e => setTask(e.target.value)} />
        <DatePicker className="input-group-prepend" placeholderText="Enter task date " selected={selectedDate} onChange={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)} showTimeSelect timeFormat="HH:mm" timeIntervals={15} timeCaption="time" dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy H:mm aa" minDate={date} /><br />
        <input className="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Submit' />

    </form>
);

  
};


export default AddTasks;
```

i have edit rules for my task want to set for Auth user but its not working      PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

```
 "rules": {
    
      "users":{
        "$user_id":{
          ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid ",
          "tasks": {
            "$task_id": {
```

i think the issue is here in "newData.hasChildren but dont know whats wrong??

```
              ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['task', 'addedAt', 'complete'])",
                
                "task":{
                  ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 "
                },
                "addedAt":{
                  ".validate": "newData.isString()"
                },
                "complete":{
                  ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
                },
                
                "$other": {
                ".validate": false
            }
            }
          },
            
        }
      }
      
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the query that's failing.  Security rules don't have much meaning without also queries that they must allow or deny.

Comment: The code needs to be in the question itself so that it will be helpful in the future in case your repo goes away.

Comment: @DougStevenson i have edited now kindly check

Comment: Your rules check for a child named `task`, but your code adds a child named `text`. That seems like a typo that would explain why the write fails.

Comment: tried that too @FrankvanPuffelen same in rules playground its Simulated set denied on.       ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'addedAt', 'complete'])",

Comment: This was definitely a cause of the error you got. But I also see you're writing to `database.ref().child('tasks');`, while the rules apply to `/users`/$uid/tasks`. There's just a lot going on with these rules and the code, which makes it hard to pinpoint the exact problems. I recommend isolating the problem in fewer rules, and simpler code. At worst that will make it more likely one of us can help, but actually also often means that you'll find the problem yourself while isolating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const AddTasks = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const newLocal = null;
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(newLocal);
    const [task, setTask] = useState('');
    const date = new Date()
```

> useSelector for uid as following

```
const userId = useSelector(state => state.auth.uid);


    const addTask = () => {
        console.log(userId);
        const payload = { id: uuid(), text: task, completed: false, addedAt: JSON.stringify(selectedDate)}
```

> then add child userId and its done

```
const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(userId).child('tasks');
            return dbtasksWrapper.child(payload.id).update(payload).then(() => {
                setTask('');
                setSelectedDate(null);
                dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload })
            })
         }
```